# ImageMagick wand not recognizing pdf image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, wand

I'm trying to use [this](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2013/07/python-converting-pdf-to-image.html) blog post to convert one pdf to a jpg, however everytime I try to run this simple script I get this exception `wand.exceptions.WandError: wand contains no images MagickWand-56' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickWriteImage/13001`

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="myFile.pdf") as img:
    img.save(filename="myFile.png")
```

I'm using the latest version of Wand and Python 3.4.2. The only thing I can think of is possibly a version compatibility issue.

Comment: I just tested this example myself on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and python 3.4.1 and it works. Are you sure "myFile.pdf" actually exists? maybe its wrong path or filename?

Comment: Yeah. I've used the full path, the relative and the filename. Same error.

Comment: Have you checked with different pdf? maybe this pdf is corrupted, or it   is not an usual one (e.g. some security rules or something else).

Comment: Just created a brand new blank 'test.pdf'. Same error.

Comment: maybe then some libraries missing. do you use linux/windows/mac? check what is required there for pdfs? ghostscript maybe?

Comment: That was it. Ran `brew install ghostscript` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcin: Please post an answer so we can vote it up!

Comment: @unutbu Thx. I just made an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So just to close the question, the problem is missing ghostscript library on mac, as indicated in my comment above:

> "maybe then some libraries missing. do you use linux/windows/mac?
>   check what is required there for pdfs? ghostscript maybe? "

Comment: In case this helps somebody else: I got the same error message, installed imagemagick with ghostscript bindings, reinstalled wand and *still* got the error along with a message complaining about X11. After I installed the latest XQuartz everything worked. This was on OS X 10.0.4